# Android/IOS Employee Subscription

Tags: android, ios, firebase-realtime-database, subscriptions

So im working on an app in which the user creates an account subscribes monthly and can add up to a certain number of employee's. Is there a way that when the owner subscribes the employee's of that account will only be allowed in if the owner is subscribed? This app will also be used on ios and im currently using firebase as a database.

Comment: Even though what you are asking is a bit vague, you can certainly do it. Since you already have a database adapted to contain the subscription information for the owner, al the applications needsto do is verify "is this employee's owner subscribed? If so, give him access ,if not, deny it".

Comment: @RicardoVieira Thank s for the reply your right though sorry my question wasn't very specific. I'm worried about 2 things, first the database Is firebase so if I use it like you say how can I prevent the person that is supposed to subscribe from just accessing that database and changing the value that he needs to be able to if he does subscribe. The second concern is if the database only changes the value (of whether or not the person is subscribed) when that person logs on then what if he pays for 1 month then never logs on again anyone else connected to that persons account can get it free.

Comment: I would say that your solution relies on a simple Model-View-Controller architecture. You define the Firebase Database Model for both Owner and Employee. You create a Middleware (Controller) such as a webservice in a programming language (any) that controls the access (defining all the actions the Owner and/or the Employee should have). Your mobile applications act as Views and the users interact with the apps sending requests to the Controller which will then be validated whether they are valid or not (for example, the owner can add or remove an employee, but the employee can not do the same)

Comment: @RicardoVieira Thanks for the help but how would i go about creating this middleware? Is there a service on firebase that might help with this?